# Is it possible to recover overwritten files on an SD card?

Tags: sd-card, file-recovery

I shot some video with my Canon 80d stored on a 32 G SD card and thought I'd transferred it all onto my external hard drive, so deleted the files, and the next day shot some more video.

Found that I had forgotten to transfer half the previous day’s footage onto my hard drive.  Downloaded several free data recovery software packages – EaseUS, Recuva and CardRecovery, but none managed to recover them, with Recuva saying they had all been overwritten and they are therefore unrecoverable.  Is there any hope...?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the most likely answer is no. The data restore industry may tell you something else, but if the files in question have been (fully) overwritten, they are not recoverable. [This](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-89862-7_21) data forensics paper concludes: It is enough to overwrite a file one time to delete it securely, i.e. make it impossible to recover the data.
And, as pointed out by @Frank Thomas, this conclusion was reached with magnetic storage in mind, where you have at least a theoretical chance to recover overwritten data - not so with flash storage.

Comment: You are correct, flash based media does not leave (recoverable) traces when overwritten. I would point out though, that the paper you reference, while a defining work on the topic, is based on Magnetic storage principals. The analog nature of magnetic fields left the theoretical  possibility that by reading the magnetic signal with greater precision than is typical, indications of prior versions of a given bit might be inferred. I believe that Guttmans initial suggestion of 35 times is based purely in math, not engineering. Flash hardware is digital at the bit level, so no such traces exist.

Comment: Congratulations; you now have the “flag posts” privilege, and you’re one upvote away from [“comment everywhere”](/help/privileges/comment).    :-)   ⁠